# How to delete a row from GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, delete-row

I am using `GridView` control in [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) 2005 [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) using .

How can I delete a particular row from `GridView`.

I have written the following code. But it's not working...

```
DataRow dr = dtPrf_Mstr.NewRow();
dtPrf_Mstr.Rows.Add(dr);
GVGLCode.DataSource = dtPrf_Mstr;
GVGLCode.DataBind();

int iCount = GVGLCode.Rows.Count;
for (int i = 0; i <= iCount; i++)
{
    GVGLCode.DeleteRow(i);
}
GVGLCode.DataBind();
```

Comment: @Kartik: If you haven't, please upvote orthod0ks's answer as well. It is essentially saying the exact same thing I did.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are deleting the row from the gridview but you are then going and calling databind again which is just refreshing the gridview to the same state that the original datasource is in.

Either remove it from the datasource and then databind, or databind and remove it from the gridview without redatabinding.

Answer (score 12):

You're deleting the row from the gridview and then rebinding it to the datasource (which still contains the row). Either delete the row from the datasource, or don't rebind the gridview afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

The default answer is to remove the item from whatever collection you're using as the GridView's DataSource.

If that option is undesirable then I recommend that you use the GridView's `RowDataBound` event to selectively set the row's (`e.Row`) `Visible` property to false.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Default3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataSet Gds = new DataSet();
   // DataColumn colm1 = new DataColumn();
   //DataColumn colm2 = new DataColumn();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("ExpId", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));

    }


    protected void BtnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //   gvLoad is Grid View Id
        if (gvLoad.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            Gds.Tables.Add(tblLoad());
        }
        else
        {
            dt = tblGridRow();
            dt.Rows.Add(tblRow());
            Gds.Tables.Add(dt);
        }
        gvLoad.DataSource = Gds;
        gvLoad.DataBind();
    }

    protected DataTable tblLoad()
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(tblRow());
        return dt;
    }
    protected DataRow tblRow()
    {
        DataRow dr;
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Exp Id"] = Convert.ToInt16(txtId.Text);
        dr["First Name"] = Convert.ToString(txtName.Text);
        return dr;
    }

    protected DataTable tblGridRow()
    {
        DataRow dr;
        for (int i = 0; i < gvLoad.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (gvLoad.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text != null)
            {

                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Exp Id"] = gvLoad.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
                dr["First Name"] = gvLoad.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text.ToString();
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            }

        }
        return dt;
    }

    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt = tblGridRow();
        dt.Rows.Add(tblRow());
        Session["tab"] = dt;
        // Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }

    protected void gvLoad_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        dt = tblGridRow();
        dt.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
        gvLoad.DataSource = dt;
        gvLoad.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    myobj.myconnection();// connection created
    string mystr = "Delete table_name where water_id= '" + GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value + "'";// query
    sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(mystr, myobj.mycon);
    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    fillgrid();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the row from the table dtPrf_Mstr rather than from the grid view.

Answer (score 0):

hi how to delete from datagridview

1.make query delete by id
2.type

```js
tabletableadaptor.delete
query(datagridwiewX1.selectedrows[0].cell[0].value.tostring);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.....

```
DataRow dr = dtPrf_Mstr.NewRow();
dtPrf_Mstr.Rows.Add(dr);
GVGLCode.DataSource = dtPrf_Mstr;
GVGLCode.DataBind();
int iCount = GVGLCode.Rows.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < iCount; i++)
{
   GVGLCode.Rows.Remove(GVGLCode.Rows[i]);
}
GVGLCode.DataBind();
```