# How to delete row in gridview using rowdeleting event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my `.cs` code :

```
protected void Gridview1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
 Gridview1.DeleteRow(e.RowIndex);
 Gridview1.DataBind();
}
```

and this is `markup`,

```
<asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" 
                                                AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDeleting="Gridview1_RowDeleting">
                    <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                 <%-- <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 2">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>--%>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Data Type">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                              <asp:DropDownList ID="ddldatatype" runat="server">
                              <asp:ListItem>varchar</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem>int</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem>numeric</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem>uniqueidentifier</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem>char</asp:ListItem>
                              </asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                        <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click"/>
                         <asp:Button ID="ButtonDel" runat="server" Text="Delete Row" OnClick="ButtonDel_Click" />
                         <input type="hidden" runat="server" value="0" id="hiddencount" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkdelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" >Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
            </asp:gridview>
```

Please sugegest me. I have done this much.. but still not deleting row...

```
 protected void Gridview1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
         {


             //Gridview1.DeleteRow((int)Gridview1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
             //Gridview1.DeleteRow(e.RowIndex);
             //Gridview1.DataBind();
             foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
             {
                 dt.Rows.Remove(dr);
                 dt.Rows[e.RowIndex].Delete();

             }
             Gridview1.DeleteRow(e.RowIndex);
            // dt = (DataTable)Gridview1.DataSource;
             Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
             Gridview1.DataBind();
       }
```

Answer (score 11):

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete From userTable (userName,age,birthPLace)");
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Surely (shirely) this is a better option using a static datatable?
Not sure about the hard coded SQL Command though.

Comment: @Rexxo Actually this hardcoded SQL command would delete all records from the table, as there's no Where statement.

Comment: Crikey, well spotted!

Answer (score 9):

Make sure to create **a static  DataTable object** and then use the following code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    dt.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex); 
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This Make sure You mention Datakeyname which is nothing but the column name (id) in your designer file

//your aspx code

<`asp:GridView ID="dgUsers" runat="server" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" OnDataBound="dgUsers_DataBound" OnRowDataBound="dgUsers_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dgUsers_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" OnRowDeleting="dgUsers_RowDeleting" DataKeyNames="id" OnRowCommand="dgUsers_RowCommand"></asp:GridView>`

//Your aspx.cs Code

```
protected void dgUsers_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {

            int id = Convert.ToInt32(dgUsers.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
            string query = "delete from users where id= '" + id + "'";
            //your remaining delete code
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your delete code looks like this

```
Gridview1.DeleteRow(e.RowIndex);
Gridview1.DataBind();
```

When you call Gridview1.DataBind() you will populate your gridview with the current datasource. So, it will delete all the existent rows, and it will add all the rows from **CustomersSqlDataSource**.

What you need to do is delete the row from the table that CustomersSqlDataSource querying.

You can do this very easy by setting a delete command to CustomersSqlDataSource, add a delete parameter, and then execute the delete command.

```
CustomersSqlDataSource.DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM Customer Where CustomerID=@CustomerID"; // Customer is the name of the table where you take your data from. Maybe you named it different 
CustomersSqlDataSource.DeleteParameters.Add("CustomerID", Gridview1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["CustomerID"].ToString());
CustomersSqlDataSource.Delete();
Gridview1.DataBind();
```

But take into account that this will delete the data from the database.

Comment: OP stated he's not using a SqlDataSource, so this answer (while correct in its own right) is not applicable to the question at hand.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was looking at Abdul Rahman code and there it was an SQL DataSource. So then user913947, where do you save the list of items ? Can you share the implementation of the function ButtonAdd_Click ??

Comment: I am adding textbox dynamically on ButtonAdd_Click... I want to remove textbox

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to create your GridView with some data source in ASP and call that data source in Row_Deletinng Event. For example if you have SqlDataSource1 as your GridView data source, your Row_Deleting event would be:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
      int ID = int.Parse(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ID").toString());
      string delete_command = "DELETE FROM your_table WHERE ID = " + ID;
      SqlDataSource1.DeleteCommand = delete_command;
}
```

Comment: Downvote for using sql injection prone concatenated sql statement.  Use parameterized queries, stored proc, or ORM db solution.

Answer (score 1):

See the following code and make some changes to get the answer for your question

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">

    void CustomersGridView_RowDeleting
        (Object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        TableCell cell = CustomersGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2];
        if (cell.Text == "Beaver")
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            Message.Text = "You cannot delete customer Beaver.";
        }
        else
        {
            Message.Text = "";
        }
    }  

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>GridView RowDeleting Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <h3>
        GridView RowDeleting Example
    </h3>
    <asp:Label ID="Message" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="CustomersGridView" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="CustomersSqlDataSource" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" 
        OnRowDeleting="CustomersGridView_RowDeleting"
        DataKeyNames="CustomerID,AddressID">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" 
                HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" 
                SortExpression="LastName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" 
                SortExpression="City" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StateProvince" HeaderText="State" 
                SortExpression="StateProvince" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="CustomersSqlDataSource" runat="server"
        SelectCommand="SELECT SalesLT.CustomerAddress.CustomerID, 
            SalesLT.CustomerAddress.AddressID, 
            SalesLT.Customer.FirstName, 
            SalesLT.Customer.LastName, 
            SalesLT.Address.City, 
            SalesLT.Address.StateProvince 
            FROM SalesLT.Customer 
            INNER JOIN SalesLT.CustomerAddress 
            ON SalesLT.Customer.CustomerID = 
                SalesLT.CustomerAddress.CustomerID 
            INNER JOIN SalesLT.Address ON SalesLT.CustomerAddress.AddressID = 
                SalesLT.Address.AddressID"
        DeleteCommand="Delete from SalesLT.CustomerAddress where CustomerID = 
            @CustomerID and AddressID = @AddressID" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AdventureWorksLTConnectionString %>">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="AddressID" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerID" />
        </DeleteParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user913947 - the process in the event handler would be the same; you'd just make changes to whatever datasource you are bound to, and then rebind.

Comment: @user913947 - See my answer for an example of what I meant.

Comment: You just copied and pasted this code from the MSDN website with absolutely no explanation to it. Seem Familiar? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdeleting.aspx

Answer (score 1):

**In Grid use this code having ID as your Primary Element so to uniquely identify each ROW**

```
<asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="Hf_ID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**and to search the uique ID use the code in C# code behind (basically this is searching hidden field and storing it in a var)**

```
protected void Grd_Registration_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        var ID = (HiddenField)Grd_Registration.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ID");
        //Your Delete Logic Goes here having ID to delete

        GridBind();

    }
```

Comment: `var id = ((HiddenField)gvImages.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ID")).Value;`

Answer (score 1):

The solution is somewhat simple; once you have deleted the row from the datagrid (Your code ONLY removes the row from the grid and NOT the datasource) then you do not need to do anything else.
As you are doing a databind operation immediately after, without updating the datasource, you are re-adding all the rows from the source to the gridview control (including the row removed from the grid in the previous statement).

To simply delete from the grid without a datasource then just call the delete operation on the grid and that is all you need to do... no databinding is needed after that.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below line in Page load,

```
ViewState["GetRecords"] = dt;
```

then try this,

```
protected void DeleteRows(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
   dt = ViewState["GetRecords"] as DataTable;
   dt.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
    dt.AcceptChanges();
    ViewState["GetRecords"] = dt;
    BindData();
}
```

If you Still have any problem, send the code in BindData() method

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing same mistake of rebinding as mentioned in this link

[How to delete row from gridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592106/how-to-delete-row-from-gridview)

Comment: I have linkbutton.. is there any code for deletion of rwo from gridview.. I m doing this without sqldatasource.. The link which u sent me, I read that, but there is not satisfaction code to me..

Answer (score 0):

If I remember from your previous questions, you're binding to a DataTable.  Try this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{

    DataTable sourceData = (DataTable)GridView1.DataSource;

    sourceData.Rows[e.RowIndex].Delete();

    GridVie1.DataSource = sourceData;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Essentially, as I said in my comment, grab a copy of the GridView's DataSource, remove the row from it, then set the DataSource to the updated object and call DataBind() on it again.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Check to see if e.RowIndex has a value or not.

Comment: plz anyone tell me how to delete row from gridiview without using sqldatasource

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the RowDeleting method in your code.  Run the program in debug mode (hit F5), delete a row, and then you can inspect the value of e.RowIndex.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick with what you want to achieve. I was also having problem like you.

Its hard to get selected row and data key in RowDeleting Event But it is very easy to get selected row and datakeys in SelectedIndexChanged event. Here's an example-

```
protected void gv_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int index = gv.SelectedIndex;
        int vehicleId = Convert.ToInt32(gv.DataKeys[index].Value);
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("-----");
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tbl WHERE vId = @vId", con);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vId", vehicleId);
        con.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I would  not recommend putting data access code in your code behind presentation code.

Answer (score 0):

```
     protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value);
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("spDelete", con);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientId", id);
        con.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer but still it would help someone in need of a solution.
I recommend to use OnRowCommand for delete operation along with DataKeyNames, keep OnRowDeleting function to avoid exception.

```
<asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDeleting="Gridview1_RowDeleting" OnRowCommand="Gridview1_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="ID">
```

Include DataKeyNames="ID" in the gridView and specify the same in link button.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkdelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>'>Delete</asp:LinkButton>

protected void Gridview1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
      int ID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
      //now perform the delete operation using ID value
    }
}

protected void Gridview1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)    
{
//Leave it blank
}
```

If this is helpful, give me +

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    MySqlCommand cmd;
    string id1 = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    con.Open();
    cmd = new MySqlCommand("delete from tableName where refno='" + id1 + "'", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    BindView();
}
private void BindView()
{
    GridView1.DataSource = ms.dTable("select * from table_name");
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//message box before deletion
protected void grdEmployee_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        foreach (DataControlFieldCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            foreach (Control control in cell.Controls)
            {
                LinkButton button = control as LinkButton;
                if (button != null && button.CommandName == "Delete")
                    button.OnClientClick = "if (!confirm('Are you sure " +
                           "you want to delete this record?')) return false;";
            }
        }
    }
}

//deletion
protected void grdEmployee_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    conn.Open();
    int empid = Convert.ToInt32(((Label)grdEmployee.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("lblIdBind")).Text);
    SqlCommand cmdDelete = new SqlCommand("Delete from employee_details where id=" + empid, conn);
    cmdDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    grdEmployee_refreshdata();

}
```

Comment: please add a description of what is logic behind code