# Removing a complete Row from a gridview when a row satisfies a condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am trying to remove a complete row from a `GridView` if it satisfied a condition.

Here I have got

`a Description Column from Product table in database` with which a `GridView` is populated.

I set the `sqlcommand` in my vb app to only `select the Description which does not contain the String s`.

Here `String s has two keywords "Tomatoes" and "Apple"`. So the Sql Query should retrieve the `Description column that does not have "Tomatoes" and "Apple"`.

Therefore the `Gridview` should be updated by removing the rows which satisfy the condition.

I am facing a difficulty in removing the

`Description row in GridView`which has "Tomatoes" and "Apple". I tried populating another GridView with the results, but it does not appear in the web page despite the fact that everything is correct because I have seen the values where I specified some Breakpoints. Any suggestions or thoughts?

Here is my code:

```
Dim cmd1 = New SqlCommand(" SELECT DISTINCT [Description] FROM [Product] WHERE ([Description] LIKE '%' + @Description + '%')", conn)
                        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", s)

         MsgBox("NO")

         For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
         DA.SelectCommand = cmd1
         DA.Fill(dt)

         'row is of a GridViewRow datatype As GridView1.Rows
          row.Cells.RemoveAt(i) '' do not know if it is correct or not

         'GridView3.DataSource = '' dt tried with no luck
         'GridView3.DataBind() '' tried with no luck
          cmd1.Dispose()
          DA.Dispose()
          dt.Clear()
          dt.Dispose()
         Next
       End If
```

Comment: A more correct implementation would be to remove the rows from the GridView's datasource, and then calling DataBind(), rather than removing data from the GridView after it's already been loaded.  See thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592106/how-to-delete-row-from-gridview).

Comment: @SandraWalters So how can I achieve only deleting the row from the gridview, because I do not want to delete the original `Description` from the sqlDataSource but rather only from the GridView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could still change the DataSource, without manipulating the original. You fill your "dt" variable with data from the database. Then loop through it with something like

```
    var stuffIActuallyWantInMyGrid = new List<DataSet>(); //A list of whatever you dt is of
    foreach(var x in dt)
    {
        if(x == WhateverMyCriteriaAre)
        {
           stuffIActuallyWantInMyGrid.Add(x);
        }
    }
    GridView3.DataSource = stuffIActuallyWantInMyGrid;
    GridView3.DataBind();
```

( Yeah, I know this is C# code, but someone tagged this question as C# ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely *must* retain the data in the GridView's underlying datasource, but don't want it displayed, one solution is to handle the RowDataBound event on the GridView.  Within this method, test the given row against your criteria; if the row matches, set its Visible property to False.

```
Public Sub MyGridView_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        If e.Row.Cells(0).Text = "((value of row to hide))" Then
            e.Row.Visible = False
        Else
            e.Row.Visible = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```