# Remove Gridview row in rowDataBound event asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, paging, rowdatabound

I have a gridview which checks some values on `rowDataBound` event.I want to remove some rows based on conditions checked in rowDataBound.I tried putting all controls in a Panel and hiding that panel ie,

**TRY 1 :**

```
protected void grdFeatured_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //some other codes here
        //IMPLEMENT FILTER ACCORDING TO ABOVE 'VIS' OUTPUT
        if (vis > 0)
        {
            Panel1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM :**

This messes up the paging since rows are hidden but page count occurs and shows page numbers for the remaining visible rows.

**TRY 2 :**

```
protected void grdFeatured_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow gvr = e.Row;
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //some other codes here
        //IMPLEMENT FILTER ACCORDING TO ABOVE 'VIS' OUTPUT
        if (vis > 0)
        {
            gvr.Parent.Controls.RemoveAt(gvr.RowIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM :**

gives error :

> ```
> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
> Parameter name: index at gvr.Parent.Controls.RemoveAt(gvr.RowIndex);
> ```

dont want to edit datasource, help me out guys .

Comment: You may have to edit your datasource as page information are calculated from the datasource

Comment: Please check out the below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592106/how-to-delete-row-from-gridview

Answer (score 5):

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (somecondition)
            {
                e.Row.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: row visibility wont affect paging and will mess it.

Comment: Only problem with this approach is that you are gonna have variable page size when you take this approach depending on how many rows get hidden on each page, lol.