# Delete rows in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a problem with deleting gridview rows. I am populating my gridview by selecting value in a dropdownlist then by clicking the add button, value will be added in my gridview, here is my code:

**In my aspx:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
            CssClass="mGrid" EmptyDataText = "There are no records to display">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="10">
        <HeaderTemplate>

        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**In my code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Id");
        DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Name");
        //DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Id");

        dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
       // dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        Session["data"] = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=GATE-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbProfile;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Profile (Id, profile_Id)VALUES(@id, @pid)", con); 
        cmdd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", row.Cells[1].Text);
        cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", txtbid.Text);
        cmdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = (DataSet)Session["data"];
    DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
    dr[0] = DropDownList1.Text.Trim();
    dr[1] = DropDownList1.SelectedItem;
    //dr[2] = txtId.Text.Trim();
    ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Now, I am trying to remove checked rows on my gridview with this code:

```
protected void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList del = new ArrayList();

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox chkDelete = (CheckBox)row.Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBox1");

            if (chkDelete != null)
            {
                if (chkDelete.Checked)
                {

                    string id = row.Cells[1].Text;
                    del.Add(id);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

With the btnRemove codes above, If I clicked it, it'll remove all values in my gridview even the unchecked rows, what I want is that just the checked rows not all. And are there any other simple way of removing rows in a gridview than using checkbox? I am using c# with asp.net.

Comment: please show the code where you have actualy deleted the items in del - arraylist

Comment: In your 3rd section of code innermost nest what is productId? did you mean id?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the rows but don't re-bind the gridview.

Use [`GridView.DeleteRow` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.deleterow.aspx) to remove the rows you filtered in the arraylist `del`.

When you call `GridView1.DataBind();` without setting a `DataSource` you will be binding nothing.

Similar

- [How to delete row from gridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592106/340760)