# How to delete a row without using OnRowDeleted/OnRowDeleting in gridview

Tags: c#

Code Behind

```
public void lbDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lb = sender as LinkButton;
    GridViewRow gvrow = lb.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    gvsize.DeleteRow(gvrow.RowIndex);
}
```

**GridView:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvsize" runat="server" ShowFooter="True" CellPadding="1" CellSpacing="2" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="Horizontal">
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
       <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkdelete" runat="server" ForeColor="Blue" OnClick="lbDelete_Click">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
       </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView >
```

There are 2 rows in my gridview which I need to delete the row using the function above.

It throws an error `"gvsize" RowDeletingEvent was not handled properly.`

Is that necessary to use `OnRowDeleted/OnRowDeleting` in gridview which I feel not necessary??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete row from gridview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592106/how-to-delete-row-from-gridview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [How to delete row from gridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592106/how-to-delete-row-from-gridview/592141#592141)

> You are deleting the row from the gridview but you are then going and
>   calling databind again which is just refreshing the gridview to the
>   same state that the original datasource is in.
>
> Either remove it from the datasource and then databind, or databind
>   and remove it from the gridview without redatabinding.

You can use row databound event to accomplish this task.

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnDel" runat="server" CommandName="DeleteRow" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Delete this Record?');"">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
```

and in the rowdatabound event you can have

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "DeleteRow")
    {
        //incase you need the row index 
        int rowIndex = ((GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
        //followed by your code 
    }
}
```

Comment: I first done DataBind, then if the row needs to be deleted? I'll delete and DataBind..

Comment: @SRIRAMRAMACHANDRAN If so you just remove row in DataSource and rebind it

Comment: Understood.. But gvsize.DeleteRow(gvrow.RowIndex) Is this not possible?? which I found simple task

Comment: Ok then tell me how to map lblDelete_Click to OnRowDeleting method..    I'll do like this.. I need delete to be displayed in all row. I'll get rowindex which needs to be deleted and I'll pass that rowindex to OnRowDeleting event which deletes the row.. Is that possible??

Answer (score 0):

Try this to delete row

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
dt.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex); 
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
 }
```

You can also delete row from another method using `Template` Column

ASPX

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDelete" runat="server" CommandName="deletenotice" ImageUrl="~/images/delete1.gif" alt="Delete"
                                    OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure want to delete the current record ?')">
                                    </asp:ImageButton>

                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

C# Code

```
 protected void gvNoticeBoardDetails_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
if (e.CommandName.ToLower().Equals("deletenotice"))
                {

                    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
                    NoticeBoard notice = new NoticeBoard();                       
                    HiddenField lblCust = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("hdngvMessageId");//Fetch the CourierId from the selected record

                    auditTrail.Action = DBAction.Delete;                       
                    Service simplyHRClient = new Service();
                    MessageClass messageClass = simplyHRClient.SaveNoticeBoard(notice, auditTrail);
                    if (messageClass.IsSuccess)
                    {

                        this.Page.AddValidationSummaryItem(messageClass.MessageText, "save");
                        showSummary.Style["display"] = string.Empty;
                        showSummary.Attributes["class"] = "success-message";


                        if (messageClass.RecordId != -1)
                            lblCust.Value = messageClass.RecordId.ToString();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.Page.AddValidationSummaryItem(messageClass.MessageText, "save");
                        showSummary.Style["display"] = string.Empty;
                        showSummary.Attributes["class"] = "fail-message";
                    }
                    //Bind Again grid
                    GetAllNoticeBoard();
                    }
             }
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Do I need to add GridView1_RowDeleting method in Gridview? as OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting "

Comment: Yes if you use `OnRowDeleting`

Comment: No.. I didnt use OnRowDeleting... I just have Delete link Button in all rows and when I click the delete: It gets the rowIndex and deletes that row using gvsize[gvrow.RowIndex]