# Why removed without selected Item from gridview in C#

Tags: c#, gridview

Please help me why my selected item not deleted from grid-view in c#.

Code:

```
rowindex = this.AB.ABProducts.Count - 1;

foreach (GridViewRow row in gc.GridRows)
{
    CheckBox chkRow = row.Cells[2].FindControl("chkID") as CheckBox;
    {
        if (rowindex >= 0)
        {
            if (chkRow.Checked)
            {

                this.AB.ABProducts.Remove(rowindex);
            }
        }
    }
    rowindex--;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered debugging your code and going through the code line for line when the program gets executed. Then see what happens and you´ll figure out whats going wrong.

Comment: Can you please explain it in details?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/592132/5358389

Comment: you are deleting the items from `this.AB.ABProducts`  not from the grid, how the items are bound to the grid?

Comment: I loaded the collection in the grid which is in the This.AB.Products. But it deleted without sselected item.

Comment: Then try rebinding the grid to get the changes reflected