# Conditional Delete after button click (radgridview)

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, telerik-grid

assume I have 2 columns in gridview : column A and column B. 
I want to delete the whole row if Column B has no value. 
this code checks column B if it doesn't have any value. next, how to enter the delete command based on the value obtained from the code ?

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRowInfo row in DGV1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[1].Value == null || Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Value) == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Null value");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe this thread can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592106/how-to-delete-a-row-from-gridview

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I can offer a couple of tips for working with `RadGridView` or really most any grid view. First, use `BeginInvoke` to avoid blocking the Click message which allows the UI thread to return from the click handler (mouse returns to the up position, any new button state is painted).

```
private void buttonRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do not block the click event.
    BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate 
    {
        onButtonRemove();
    });
}
```

Next make an array of records (or rows) that need to be removed. If your view is bound to a `DataSource` this is especially easy using `System.Linq`. Then simply remove from `DataSource`.

```
void onButtonRemove()
{
    // Perform Linq query to see what needs to be removed
    var removes = 
        DataSource
        .Where(record => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(record.ColumnB));

    // Cast to an array before iterating to
    // avoid "CollectionWasModified" exception.
    foreach (var record in removes.ToArray())
    {
        DataSource.Remove(record);
    }
}
```

This *particular* code defines a row with this `Record` class:

```
class Record
{
    public string ColumnA { get; set; } = "SomeValue";
    public string ColumnB { get; set; }
}
```

If you were using a Winforms `DataGridView` it could initialize like this:

```
BindingList<Record> DataSource = new BindingList<Record>();
private void InitializeDataGridView()
{
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = DataSource;
    // Add one or more records to auto-create columns.
    DataSource.Add(new Record { ColumnB = "Not empty or null"});
    DataSource.Add(new Record { ColumnB = String.Empty});
    DataSource.Add(new Record { ColumnB = null});

    // Column formatting
    dataGridView1.Columns[nameof(Record.ColumnA)].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
    dataGridView1.Columns[nameof(Record.ColumnB)].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
}
```

[image: before and after]

Your post is for `Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadGridView` but the initialization is very similar:

```
BindingList<Record> DataSource = new BindingList<Record>();
private void InitializeDataGridView()
{
    DGV1.DataSource = DataSource;
    // Add one or more records to auto-create columns.
    DataSource.Add(new Record { ColumnB = "Not empty or null"});
    DataSource.Add(new Record { ColumnB = String.Empty});
    DataSource.Add(new Record { ColumnB = null});

    // Column formatting
    DGV1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = GridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
}
```

[image: RadGridView]

Hope this helps get you where you want to be.

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/conditional-delete-after-button-click.git) this sample.